# Unable to forward all traffic from one interface to another with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a Raspberry Pi (stretch) that is connected to the Internet via ethernet. I would like to forward all network traffic from wlan0 to eth0 but am having trouble doing so. Am I missing something?

```
// Setting up port forwarding rules
root@raspi:/home/pi# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
root@raspi:/home/pi# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
root@raspi:/home/pi# iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
root@raspi:/home/pi# iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT


// Listing iptable rules
root@raspi:/home/pi# iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 128 packets, 17968 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   wlan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wlan0  eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 99 packets, 16689 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination


// Able to ping Google (8.8.8.8) via eth0
root@raspi:/home/pi# ping 8.8.8.8 -I eth0
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.0.201 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=14.1 ms


// Unable to ping Google via wlan0
root@raspi:/home/pi# ping 8.8.8.8 -I wlan0
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 169.254.160.66 wlan0: 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Comment: @A.B - Do you mean that I should execute `ping 8.8.8.8 -I wlan0` on another node on my mesh Batman-adv network? I have tried pinging over wlan0 and bat0 over my other two nodes, but was unable to hit Google.

Comment: I used `-I wlan0` because I want to ping Google specifically wlan0 to verify `wlan0` interface is forwarding traffic correctly to `eth0`. What else could be the problem that is preventing me from forwarding traffic? Note that I've been able to block traffic to Google via `iptables -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8 -j DROP`.

Comment: I'm confused at why would running `ping 8.8.8.8 -I wlan0` on my router not work. If I am correctly forwarding all my network traffic from wlan0 to eth0 on my router, then shouldn't pinging Google on wlan0 forward my request to eth0, and then onto Google? I'm sorry, what other details do you need - I'm happy to provide it to you.